# GFCI outlet red light

Tags: electrical

I came home to unusual burning smell, and I checked out the bathroom and the room next to it, and the smell origin I found out to be the GFCI outlet in the bathroom.

However it was working fine when I inserted receptacle tester, this is how it looks:

[image]

What do I do now? I don't have the instructions I didn't set this one up, came with the house. Everything works fine just the red light seems to be unusual.

Comment: Unless the light changed color recently, this manufacturer probably just used a red LED rather than a green one and its indicating normal operation...

Comment: Did the GFCI have a red light on previously, or is this new?

Comment: @keshlam yes it was not red before

Comment: If you pull the receptacle out of the box, you'll likely find the manufacturer name and possibly the model number printed in it somewhere.

Comment: If the light flashing, or on solid?

Comment: I think solid red means a ground-fault. Solid green means power on. Flashing red means loss of GFCI protection.

Comment: I had a very similar situation: GFCI at the start of a circuit with a solid red light that was otherwise operating. It could do the test/reset cycle as normal, and I had run power tools, shop lights, etc off the circuit with no problems, but the red indicator light seemed odd to me. I investigated after plugging a working TV into the circuit and discovering that it tripped the GFCI every time it powered on, and yes, the GFCI was faulty. Replaced it with a new one and the TV works fine now. I'll add an answer below as I do not believe the existing answer is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, GFIs with a red or orange indicator light signal a tripped GFI. In fact, yours definitely looks tripped as the "reset" button looks popped out. In this case the receptacles definitely should NOT be working.

First things first, push the "test" button. If nothing happens and the light is on and the receptacles still work, replace the device immediately. It is not likely with a newer GFI receptacle, but it is possible for it to fail in the on position.

If the test button pushes in and the reset button pops out more, and the receptacles stop working that signals a proper test. If you can press the reset button back in, and the receptacles then work, you should be fine.

I am leaning towards the former being the case though, especially considering the electronic smell you are experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to look up the receptacle model and find the manufacturer's documentation, that will give you a definitive answer, but it appears most GFCIs use a solid red light to indicate an error, *not* a normal tripped state. For example, [Leviton's site](https://blog.leviton.com/gfci-status-indicator-light) states:

> If, during a self-test, the GFCI detects a potential problem, one indicator is a solid or blinking red light. In this case, simply press the TEST and RESET buttons to reset the GFCI. If the device resets, you’re good to go. If the GFCI will NOT reset or the solid or blinking red light continues, the device has somehow been compromised and must be replaced.